# Unable to route all pins for MAX30208CLB+ in eagle

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I am trying to create a circuit using MAX30208CLB+ however 4 pins of the chip are underneath the IC due to which I am unable to route all the signals in eagle. Can someone point me how can I route the pins when they are below the IC.

Comment: Is your design 2 layer or multilayer?

Comment: Its a 2 layer design

Comment: Use vias to the bottom copper layer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used tRestrict, bRestrict or vRestrict layers in the component? They would prevent or warn you for routing the signals?

If those are ok, you need to check DRC settings. You can write "DRC" while the board layout window is active or select it from the toolbar. Take a look at the "Clearance" section and refer to your PCB manufacturer for good minumum values. (0.15 mm should be ok in general for many settings)

DRC settings might have been overridden by edit->net classes menu.